# Why is "in" missing in "Alles Geld der Welt"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase

The film title translation of "All the Money in the World" is "Alles Geld der Welt", which seems to translate back to English as "All Money The World". Why are the German words for "the" and "in" missing in this German translation?

Comment: Simple answer: it's not the same language and grammar works differently and translation never works word-for-word but in a way to capture the same meaning

Comment: It should be noted as well that film title translations are often wildly inaccurate. My favorite example is "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly" which was translated relatively faithfully from the Italian *Il buono, il brutto, il cattivo*. But the German title is *Zwei glorreiche Halunken*; yikes!

Comment: It seems you overlooked  in your backwards translation, that *der* for a feminine substantive indicates genitive. The adjusted *All money of the world* also looks like valid English to me.

Comment: “All money of the world” is not valid English. 1. In German they don’t say “all the”, they just say “all”. 2. “Der” functions as both the English words “the” and “of”. It’s the genitive case, signifying possession, like the English ending ‘s.

Comment: @PeterElbert if your answer is contra to, or is more detailed then the others, then convert your comment to an answer

Comment: "der Welt" is genitive here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The construction of the sentences in English and German is a bit different. In the English sentence, you describe where the money is ("in the world"). In the German sentence, you describe whose money it is ("der Welt"). If you would translate both sentences more literally, you'd get something like

> All the money in the world.
> Alles Geld in der Welt.

and

> Alles Geld der Welt.
> All the world's money.

But both of those more literal versions are not very natural ;)

As a side note, "Geld" is spelled with a "d" at the end, and nouns are typically capitalized ("Geld" as well as "Welt").

Comment: You could add that “der Welt” is the possessive case of “die Welt”.

Comment: @Carsten S: Of course *in der Welt* (dative) would still be correct. Part of the problem is that the English is not meant to be taken literally; the world isn't some giant safe containing stacks of money. I'm sure the figurative meaning would be understood in German as well, but perhaps the genitive is more idiomatic for German.

Comment: I'm not sure, yet I'd prefer "XXX auf der Welt" over "XXX in der Welt". Usually 'Welt' or 'Erde' is a 2D surface in German, so you search on it, not in it. That's different with universe or if you literally search for ressources and mean literally 'in the ground' when using 'Erde'.

Comment: I wouldn't say that "der Welt" is meant to describe **whose** money it is - although it is the genitive of "Welt". The world cannot possess money; imo the phrase means "all the money worldwide".